# Is this positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, toeplitz-matrices

Given $n \times (n+m-1)$ Toeplitz matrices $A$ and $B$, if $AB^T$ is positive definite, how to prove that

$$\left( A^T - B^T \right) \left( BB^T \right)^{-1} B + I$$

is also positive definite?

Comment: Define "convolution matrix". This term has different meanings in different fields. Also, define the operator "$\ast$".

Comment: Positive definiteness is usually meaningful in the context of symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Convolution matrix is Toeplitz and upper triangular matrix with dimensions n$\times$(n+m-1):

\begin{pmatrix} 
  a_1  &   a_2 & a_3 & .. & a_m  & 0 & ..&  & 0\\  
  0 & a_1  &   a_2 & a_3 & .. & a_m  & 0 & .. & 0\\  
& .. & .. &.. & .. & .. & .. & .. \\
 0 & .. &  0 & 0 & 0 & .. & a_{m-1} &a_{m-1} & a_m &  
\end{pmatrix}

"*" means matrix multiplication. I corrected it.

Note that $(BB^T)^{-1}B=B^\dagger$, where $\dagger$ denotes pseudoinversion.